# SQL multiple values, table design

Tags: sql, database-design

This is more of a question about structure more than the programming language itself.  I have a very basic knowledge of SQL.

If you have a table with products and each product can have multiple or no colors.

```
Table: Color
Columns: Id, ColorName

1, Black
2, White  
3, Purple  
4, Red
```

and then we have

```
Table: Phone
Columns: Id, PhoneName, PhoneManf, ColorID
```

eg. Phone Table could have a HTC EVO that is available in black and white

would this mean that for every color of every phone there would be a record.
i.e.

```
1, EVO, HTC, 1
2, EVO, HTC, 2
3, Curve, Blackberry,1
4, Curve, Blackberry,3
```

Or is there a way to have 1 record for each phone where the color key is like an array ?

Sorry if this is a very basic question, I am newish to this and want to make sure I am starting off right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple normalization

```
Table: Color
Columns: ColorId, ColorName
Primary Key: ColorId

// table for the many-to-many relationship
// between Colors and Phones
Table: PhoneColor
Columns: PhoneId, ColorId
Primary Key: (PhoneId, ColorId)
Foreign Key: PhoneId
Foreign Key: ColorId

Table: Phone
Columns: PhoneId, PhoneName, PhoneManfId
Primary Key: PhoneId
Foreign Key: PhoneManfId

Table: PhoneManf
Columns: PhoneManfId, PhoneManfName, PhoneManfAddress
Primary Key: PhoneManfId
```

Any other details you have regarding phones, like SKU should go to table Phone (or Model if you want to call it that way).

Details for Manufacturers should go to table PhoneManf, etc.

Comment: thanks, ill start and see where i get to from there :).. looking forward to getting this simple db out of the way.  Its a great learning experience.

Answer (score 4):

Duplicating essential data (like phone model and manufacturer) just because it is available under other colors is unecessary redundancy.

Better create a table like `phone_color (IdPhone, IdColor)`

Comment: In the real world, databases are designed by people who don't know normalization principles, but instead by guys who have just been at the company for 20 years and know "the business." It's only right that starts to work with crappy database layouts now so he has real world experience!

Comment: @glowcoder Yeah, I'm unfortunately very aware of that. We're in the middle of a two-month-long refactoring because some [contained rage] person [/contained rage] decided to duplicate database records for start-end dates instead of using two fields in a single record.

Comment: with that correct logic, should i also have a lookup table for the manufacture to model as well ? or should it be left as is? As its more of of 1 to many relationship ?  eg. Samsung produces , Instinct, Epic etc...

Comment: @patrick: Yes, you should! Normalization is essential. 1 manufacturer-many models (1-to-many), models to colours (many-to-many relationship, you have that with mdrg's suggestion.)

Comment: @ypercube: Thanks, quick question as I am new to this, so forgive my ignorance (I am still reading up on all this). With regards to the (1-to-many) relationship why would it require a look up table as well ?

Comment: Suppose you have the Table: Phone with 
Columns: Id, PhoneName, PhoneManf. Then you have the same values for PhoneManf ('Ericsson', 'Nokia') etc. in many rows. There are many problems with this, like what happens if Nokia changes name to 'SuperNokia'? You'd have to update all (hudreds) of rows of Nokia phones. What happens if you want to add a ManufAddress column?, etc...

Comment: @ypercube,  Thanks that makes sense , I am just trying to figure out now where the Model of the phone would go.  I guess I would create another table called Tbl_Model and have a PkID, Sku and Model Name. Then just use link off the Pkid to the Tbl_PhoneManf

Comment: SKU and ModelName should go to table Model or Phone (whatever you want to call the table). Answering in detail below, as I can't properly format here.

Answer (score 3):

You need a many-many relationship. You need a 3rd "mapping" table called PhoneColor. See http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/many-to-many.html for more insight.

Answer (score 2):

You can just create another table:

```
Table: PhoneColor
Columns: PhoneId, ColorId
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is create a bridging table called phone_color  with one column for phone and another for color.  These columns store the respective ids mapping the many-to-many relationship.

So given the data above your rows in the bridging table would be

```
1,1
2,2
3,1
4,3
```

Hope that helps.